# Zend Framework multiple form elements names

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have multiple Zend Framework(v1.12) forms in my application.

Main form:

```
<?php

class Application_Form_Main extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post')->setAction('some/url');
    }
}

?>
```

My subform:

```
<?php

class Application_Form_User extends Zend_Form_SubForm
{

    public function init()
    {

       //first name element
        $this->addElement('text', 
                          'first_name', 
                          array(
                            'label'      => 'Name',
                            'required'   => true,  
                            'filters'    => array('StringTrim')           
                          )
        );

        //last name element
        $this->addElement('text', 
                          'last_name', 
                          array(
                            'label'      => 'Surname',
                            'required'   => true,
                            'filters'    => array('StringTrim')           
                          )
        );

        $this->setElementDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors'
        )); 
    }    

}

?>
```

In my custom controller (for example UsersController.php) Im rendering main form with multiple user subforms:

```
<?php 

$mainForm = new Application_Form_Main();

for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){

    $userForm = new Application_Form_User();              

    $mainForm->addSubForm($userForm, 'user_'.($i+1)); 

}       

//passing main form to the template
$this->view->mainForm = $mainForm;

?>
```

So Im getting the form with 2 users first_name and last_name fields.

In my template Im rendering form this way:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->mainForm->getAction(); ?>"
      enctype="<?php echo $this->form->getEnctype(); ?>"
      method="<?php echo $this->form->getMethod(); ?>"
">

<?php echo $this->mainForm->getSubForm('user_1')->first_name; ?>
<?php echo $this->mainForm->getSubForm('user_1')->last_name; ?>

<?php echo $this->echo $this->mainForm->getSubForm('user_2')->first_name; ?>
<?php echo $this->echo $this->mainForm->getSubForm('user_2')->last_name; ?>

</form>
```

The problem is first_name and last_name text field names are identical in both forms. How can I make it to have unique names? If I output the form:

```
<?php echo $this->mainForm; ?>
```

Then everything is ok, I get different field names.

So any ideas?